# RestSharp - How do I get the numerical http response code?

Tags: c#, http, restsharp

I'm using the [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) HTTP client library for C#.

How I would retrieve the actual numerical http response code?  Not only do I not see a property containing the numerical code but I don't even see it in the headers collection.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply grab the StatusCode property off of the [RestResponse](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/658f0984e3ec71f2119f50f7de878f155246e9ce/RestSharp/RestResponse.cs) object and cast the enum value to int.

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
int numericStatusCode = (int)statusCode;
```

Comment: Terrific.  I had failed to realize that IRestResponse.StatusCode (or RestResponse.StatusCode) was of type HttpStatusCode.

Answer (score -2):

```
Assert.Equal(200, (int)response.StatusCode);
```