# How to handle custom http error code in RestSharp .NET

Tags: c#, http, restsharp, webapi, http-error

How to handle custom HTTP error codes in RestSharp, IRestResponse.HttpStatusCode is not allowing to handle 599 or other custom codes, is there any way to handle it? please help

We have a certain situation, where we are getting 599 in HttpStatusCode

Answer (score 1):

Check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30765942/1543596).

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
int numericStatusCode = (int)statusCode;
```